# When was co-NP introduced for the first time?

Tags: np, ho.history-overview

My best finding is Pratt's 1975 [article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/533b/a306dbd8e4f483372d177d898ef4963c9a02.pdf). Is there any earlier mention of co-NP?

Comment: If you read Jack Edmond's 1965 article "Minimum partition of a matroid into independent subsets" (referenced in Pratt's article), it's clear he understood NP and co-NP, but he used the terminology "good characterization" instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Albert R. Meyer and Larry J. Stockmeyer introduced the polynomial hierarchy in 1972 with their paper ["the equivalence problem for regular expressions with squaring requires exponential space"](https://doi.org/10.1109/SWAT.1972.29). The class $\Pi_1^P$ in there is of course coNP. Stockmeyer wrote a [full paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(76)90061-X) on the polynomial hierarchy (TCS 1977) which also uses the notation coNP.

Comment: I think you meant their 1972 "The equivalence problem for regular expressions with squaring requires exponential space" paper (DOI: 10.1109/SWAT.1972.29), not "word problems requiring exponential time (preliminary report)". $\Pi_1^P$ is defined on page 28. Moreover, Stockmeyer confirms this initial reference in his 1977 "The Polynomial Hierarchy" paper at p.5.

Comment: Many thanks for the catches! I'll update my answer accordingly